# undefined method `user' when using rspec controller specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to write controller specs for my rails api application. Authentication is done using devise and some custom auth-token method. Here is the auth method:

```
def authenticate_user_with_token!
  token = params[:auth_token]

  if user = User.find_by_authentication_token(token)
    puts user
    sign_in user, store: false
  else
    fail InvalidAuthTokenError
  end
end
```

However, running a following spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::JobsController, :type => :controller, current: true do

  describe "GET #index" do
    before do
      @advisor = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :service_advisor)
    end

    it "responds successfully with an HTTP 200 status code" do
      get :index, auth_token: @advisor.authentication_token
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
  end

end
```

throws:

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
```

on that line: `sign_in user, store: false`. Have you any idea what am i doing wrong?

Rails 4.1.0
Ruby 2
RSpec 3

Comment: use `User.find_by authentication_token: token` in Rails 4

Comment: Add `expect(User).to receive(:find_by_authentication_token).and_return(@advisor.user)` before `get`

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?